# perl6: passing an Array of UInt fails, while an Array of Int succeeds

Tags: arrays, raku

If I execute the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl6
use v6.c;
use fatal;

sub foo(Int:D @nums) {
    say @nums.join(" ");
}

sub bar(UInt:D @nums) {
    say @nums.join(" ");
}

my UInt:D @nums = (1, 2);
say "foo: ";
foo(@nums);
say "bar: ";
bar(@nums);
```

I get the following output:

```
foo: 
1 2
bar: 
Constraint type check failed for parameter '@nums'
  in sub bar at ./test.p6 line 9
  in block <unit> at ./test.p6 line 17
```

But I don't understand, why it makes a difference, if I use UInt- or Int-Arrays. Is this possibly a bug?

I am using Rakudo version 2016.12 built on MoarVM version 2016.12 (which is included in Debian stretch)

Comment: `Int` is a type, `UInt` is a subtype of `Int` (a subtype is not really a type). This has some ramifications with how it works. It may be that no-one has tried this who has knowledge of the internals of Rakudo, and no one has reported this as a bug yet.

Comment: It is on the bug queue [function prototypes using array of subset type give type error](https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=131381)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the bugreport.

Comment: Unrelated to the question but you might want to consider jumping to a newer release. The language hasn't changed but the performance changes in the last 6 months are significant. Debian sid is on 2017.06-1 given there are very few external dependencies, if it was me, I would do some package pinning to get the sid version of Rakudo locally.

Comment: Thanks for you advice, but because I use perl6 for administration-purposes and not for production, I currently don't need speed, (because my perl6-scripts are only gluing shell-commands together.) It's much better to use a package which is in stable, because I currently have already to many packages which are from sid or somewhere else, so my goal is, to keep the number of external packages as small as possible. 
If I need speed, I use C++, but thanks anyway, I didn't expected that.

Comment: Just for the record, I didn't submit it on the bug queue. I didn't even find the bug report. I just [posted this](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2017-08-19#i_15043638) to `#perl6` on freenode.net, and someone else found the report.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in the error message. If you use a newer one like 2018.03 it says

```
Constraint type check failed in binding to parameter '@nums'; expected UInt but got Array[UInt] (Array[UInt].new(1, 2))
```

That said, you can change your code to:

```
use v6;
use fatal;

sub foo( @nums where { @nums ~~ Array[Int] } ) {
    say @nums.join(" ");
}

sub bar( @nums where { @nums ~~ Array[UInt] } ) {
    say @nums.join(" ");
}

my UInt @nums = (1, 2);
say "foo: ";
foo(@nums);
say "bar: ";
bar(@nums);
```

Which will behave, I guess, as expected:

```
Constraint type check failed in binding to parameter '@nums'; expected anonymous constraint to be met but got Array[UInt] (Array[UInt].new(1, 2))
in sub foo at uint.p6 line 6
in block <unit> at uint.p6 line 16
```

This seems the only practical way to constrain positionals, since most others yield an error.